# AWS Lambda "no module named 'grpc'" despite including it in the function zip file

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to get a (for now) simple gRPC client function working in AWS Lambda.  I've read up on building a function ZIP file containing the dependencies using python virtualenv, and within my build environment, with the venv activated, the function works.  However, when I upload the .zip to AWS Lambda, I get "No module named 'grpc'" when the function runs.

I'm building the zip file in Docker with the following DockerFile:

```
FROM amazonlinux:latest as lambda-build

RUN \
  yum install -y python3 python3-pip curl zip \
  && yum clean all

RUN python3 -m pip install virtualenv

COPY index.py /opt/lambda-function/
COPY gRPC /opt/lambda-function/gRPC/

RUN \
  cd /opt/lambda-function \
  && pip3 install --upgrade pip \
  && python3 -m virtualenv . \
  && source ./bin/activate \
  && python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip \
  && python3 -m pip install cygrpc grpcio google-api-python-client watchtower \
  && deactivate

RUN \
  cd /opt/lambda-function \
  && cd lib/python*/site-packages \
  && zip -r /opt/lambda-function_lambda.zip . \
  && cd /opt/lambda-function/ \
  && zip -g -r /opt/lambda-function_lambda.zip *.py gRPC/*.py
```

`index.py` looks like this (simplified):

```
import logging 
import grpc
import gRPC.bookingsapi_pb2 as bookingsapi_pb2
import gRPC.bookingsapi_pb2_grpc as bookingsapi_pb2_grpc

def getGRPCStatus():
   # gRPC stuff here

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Entrypoint when running as AWS lambda
    getGRPCStatus()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    getGRPCStatus()
```

I then upload the resulting .zip to AWS Lambda and hit TEST which gives me

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'index': No module named 'grpc'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

I can't see why it works within the build environment venv but not in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.  I had made the assumption that `lib64` would just be a symlink to `lib` and both would be the same, hence I was just zipping up `lib`.  In actual fact, in this venv, it was not a symlink and the gRPC modules were getting installed in `lib64`.  I put `lib64` in to my zip (and left out `lib`, nothing in there I needed so managed a smaller zip) and it worked when uploaded to Lambda.

I got to this eureka moment when I realised I could find where the grpc module was being loaded from in the working environment by doing

```
import grpc
print(grpc)
```

which lead me to the `lib64` directory.